# How to implement renderTo on the fly

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have this simple code, in which I iterate through a form fields:

```
frm.getFields().each(function(field) {
    ....
});
```

What I want to achieve is to render some fields to some html elements (in case some condition is met - which in fact does not matter). So, I want to implement something like:

```
frm.getFields().each(function(field) {
    if(ok){
        field.renderTo(document.getElementById(some_id));
    }
});
```

I know how it statically works, just like:

```
Ext.create(..., function(){
    renderTo:...
});
```

But I want to do this dynamically, like I said above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

renderTo is the config option, if you need to render an ExtJS component use the render method.

Something like:

```
<div id="renderHere"></div>

var myField = Ext.create({
        xtype : 'textfield',
        fieldLabel : 'Test'
    });

myField.render('renderHere');
```